# Syntax error occurs when importing external Javascript library

Tags: javascript, html, web

I downloaded a Javascript library called "uuid.js" from
https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid/blob/master/uuid.js

Then I put this file in the current directory as the page that uses it.
I imported "uuid.js" using

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='uuid.js' />
```

But then I receviced this error.
**SyntaxError: syntax error**

From the Firefox web console I got this: uuid.js:10

How can I fix this error? I'm new to web development.

Thank you

Comment: What line does it point to?

Comment: (the SyntaxError...what line does the SyntaxError point to?)

Comment: From the Firefox web console I got this: uuid.js:10

Comment: Script tags aren't self closing. You need to use the syntax `<script src="uuid.js"></script>`

Comment: To j08691: I tired your way, but it did not work.

Comment: Can you post more code here?

Comment: To Felix: The rest of my Perl:Mason file produces no error. If I remove 'uuid.js', then everything works.